# Differences in behavior running on device w/ Xcode vs. running on device w/o Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, singleton

I'm a novice working through an old Objective C XCode project, when I noticed some unexpected behavior: **a singleton behaves as expected when I run the project on an iPhone XSMax from XCode. It behaves differently when I run it on the iPhone without Xcode.**

In this radio station app, I'm using the Basemodel Cocoapod (https://github.com/nicklockwood/BaseModel) as the basis for a singleton to store and persist favorite songs the user chooses as they listen to the radio. Each favorite item consists of several properties of strings, including track name, title, album, including one NSDictionary item that contains four value/key pairs for some html about the artist.

The user presses a button on a VC to save the current track info (trackInfoSRK) into a mutable array of other favorite tracks, that's then saved.

```
//FavoriteItem.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "BaseModel.h"

@interface FavoriteItem : BaseModel;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate *time;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSTimeZone *listenedTimeZone;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *artist;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *album;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *year;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *duration;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSURL *albumURL;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *albumImg;
@property BOOL albumErr;
@property BOOL albumLoaded;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSMutableDictionary *trackInfo;

@end
```

```
//FavoriteItem.m
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "FavoriteItem.h"
#import "FavoriteList.h"

@implementation FavoriteItem

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.albumErr=FALSE;
        self.albumLoaded=FALSE;
    }   
   return self;
}

- (BOOL)save
{
    //save the favorites list
    return [[FavoriteList sharedInstance] save];
}
@end
```

```
//FavoriteList.h
@interface FavoriteList : BaseModel
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *favorites;
@end


//FavoriteList.m
#import "FavoriteList.h"
#import "FavoriteItem.h"

@implementation FavoriteList

- (void)setUp
{
    self.favorites = [NSMutableArray array];
}

+ (BMFileFormat)saveFormat
{
    //return BMFileFormatHRCodedJSON;
    return BMFileFormatHRCodedXML;
}

@end
```

When the properties are set in a VC:

```
//trackInfoSRK is currently playing trackInfo dict, and it set up in viewDidLoad:

trackInfoSRK = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                 @"", @"PAArtistHTML",
                 @"", @"PAArtistLink",
                 @"", @"lastFMArtistHTML",
                 @"", @"lastFMArtistLink",nil];

//trackInfoSRK is populated along the way. Then when it's favorited:

FavoriteItem *thisFavorite =[[FavoriteItem alloc] init];
thisFavorite.artist = artistName;
thisFavorite.title = songTitle;
.
.
.
thisFavorite.trackInfo = trackInfoSRK;
[[FavoriteList sharedInstance].favorites insertObject:thisFavorite atIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"Adding Favorite at index 0");
BOOL saveGood=[[FavoriteList sharedInstance] save];
```

This works just fine when the app is running on an iPhone XSMax launched from Xcode. However, when the app run by itself on the phone, any favorite and the contained properties are saved to the mutable array are saved properly **except** for the dictionary trackInfo property: the trackInfo for any new favorite made will instantly show the trackInfo for the currently playing track, trackInfoSRK (all the rest of the string properties are fine).

**It's like the favorited track's trackInfo becomes a pointer to the variable it was being set to from the currently playing track, and it will always mirror that until the app is restarted** (at which point the favorite is frozen to the last trackInfoSRK it had in this "mirroring" state.

1. Why would any behavior change from running it in Xcode on the device from running it standalone on the device?
2. What should I be looking for in this sense that would tell me how to fix this? I feel like I'm missing something Big But Simple here.

I'm using Xcode 10.2.1 with SDK 12.2. Deployment Target is iOS 11.0.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you described it exactly with, "the favorited track's trackInfo becomes a pointer to the variable".  Make a copy of trackInfoSDK instead.  Something like, `thisFavorite.trackInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:trackInfoSDK];`